# selenium webdriver manage speed?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

I've just updated my selenium WebDriver from a pretty old version which allowed me to control the driver speed via the following:

```
var _driver = new FireFoxDriver();
_driver.Manage().Speed = Speed.Medium;
```

after installing FireFox 7, running the selenium tests my project no-longer worked.  so i upgraded the dll's via nuGet for 2.8.0.0 and now the ability to manage the speed has gone.

any other way to do this?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just used Thread.Wait(3000) after each action.. not ideal but works

Answer (score 1):

there is something called implicit wait which acts as a global timeout not sure about c# but java code for it is as follows-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```