# How to adjust speed of nunit test cases in C# or in nunit interface?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have used selenium IDE and created test cases. I have converted them to Nunit with C# and I started running testcases. How can I adjust speed of running test cases using either nunit interface or C# code. (In selenium ide interface, I could able to adjust speed so as to run test case slowly.)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't do this.  It will increase the probability of poorly-written tests working, but it won't make them stable.  You really should modify the tests to properly synchronize with the application instead.

Comment: The reason someone might want to do this, for example you have some slow rendering pages or JavaScript running after each driver selection which causes the tests to fall over as a computer will try and click/select/type into something that is not quite ready yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `TestFixtureSetup` to each `TestFixture`.  The example below should run before each test and cause a 5 second wait:

```
[TestFixture]
public MyTests()
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        System.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: +1. Shove this into a base class that acts as a base test fixture, and then you can have it on every test fixture setup. Although, I'm not entirely sure why the OP wants this.

Answer (score 0):

One of these links ought to work:

similar SO question:

[selenium webdriver manage speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889137/selenium-webdriver-manage-speed)

Forum result for selenium (http://seleniumforum.forumotion.net/t376-to-control-of-speed-execute-in-selenium-rc):

```
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", URL");
selenium.Start();
selenium.SetSpeed("1000");

}
```

Comment: Is your StackOverflow link not a link to this question?!.....Note, what you've suggested here is Selenium v1 code.

Comment: Whoops, bad paste.  Thanks Arran.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this quite a lot over the past few days. By far the simplest way to solve this is to create a driver property, rather than a variable and add a wait to the get.

```
  private IWebDriver _driver;
    public IWebDriver driver
    {
        get{ Thread.Sleep(500);
            return _driver;
        }

        set
        { _driver = value; }
    }
```

This means that anytime your driver is requested, which is anytime you do anything in the browser, it will slow it down by the specified amount.